# Horizontal scroll view with semi paging on android

Tags: android, uiscrollview, horizontal-scrolling

What is the way to implement horizontal scroll view similar to the one google play store uses?

I.e. when I scroll with average or high velocity I get 4 item scrolled, but when I scroll with low velocity it scrolls only 1 item. Also I can not scroll less than 1 item.

[image]

Comment: Not sure but it might be a ViewPager with a different getPageWidth on the Adapter.